# how create Yii2 backend that have some admins but different roles

Tags: yii2, backend

Please help me, i am new at yii2. I wanna creat yii2 admin panel that will be logon with admins.but one admin can do anything he want in adminpanel,but others can only view some limited content. 
Thanks everyone!

Comment: Wait, what's the question? You want to have admin accounts with differen permissions?

Comment: You want and admin and a superAdmin?

Comment: my program must be like this:1)There are a mainadmin and a lot of secondadmins. Main admin can create,edit secondadmins and while creating and editing mainadmin will creat  passwords and usernames for secondadmins. and Secondadmins will login and see only a page.With this page secondadmins can create their child admins and give them their own   usernames and passwords.Also admins can see all the mysql database table but child-secondadmins can see  only limited mysql tables.

Comment: You should really update your question instead of adding comments... It's not clear at all as it is now and it will probably be closed if you don't make it more clear.